# Need help Migrating from legacy SDK (appcfg)

Tags: google-app-engine, appcfg

Google has emailed me saying "Migrate your App Engine projects from the legacy SDK (appcfg)" for 3 of my projects. I don't use appcfg, I use mvn to deploy my software. I've 6 projects in total on GAE and have compared the pom files and build files and they are identical. I thought it was because I'm using an older appengine-api, but they are fairly up to date and all use the same version:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
  <artifactId>appengine-api-1.0-sdk</artifactId>
  <version>1.9.58</version>
</dependency>
```

What I am missing here?
Thanks
Tim

Answer (score 0):

So you basically want to know why would Google send you that email if your projects do not use appcfg?. It could be because:

1.- Just a reminder that you should migrate to the new SDK. If is not specified on the email something like "we have noticed that your project --- is using ..." then is probably just a general reminder.

2.- You have previous versions where you used the legacy SDK, and Google is detecting this.

3.- You are using a deprecated version of [Java App Engine SDK-based plugin](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/tools/migrate-maven) and have to migrate to the new version (less likely but since you are in fact using Maven wouldn't hurt to check).

Also, i know that you said you weren't using appcfg but here's a list of [equivalents commands between appcfg and gcloud](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/tools/migrating-from-appcfg-to-gcloud) for extra information.